# Learning about Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why can't I access the method inside of the Daily class from the main located in the Test class. Specifically the occursOn() method is the one that I would like to access form the main. If I create an object originally of type Daily then it allows me to access the occursOn() method but if I originally declare it as a general Appointment then it doesn't.

I'm trying to teach myself polymorphism btw.

```
public class Appointment{

private String description;
private String date;

public Appointment(){
    this.description = "";
    this.date = "";
}
public Appointment(String de, String da){
    this.description = de;
    this.date = da;
}

public void setDescription(String d){
    this.description = d;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return this.description;
}
public void setDate(String d){
    this.date = d;
}
public String getDate(){
    return this.date;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Appointment [description=" + description + ", date=" + date + "]";
}
}

public class Daily extends Appointment{

public Daily(){
    super();
}
public Daily(String de, String da){
    super(de, da);
}

public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day){
    return true;
}
public String toString(){
    String str = "Daily " + super.toString();
    return str;
}
}

public class Test {

public static void main(String [] args){

    Appointment appt1;

    appt1 = new Onetime("See doctor", "01/01/2015");

}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because child classes inherit the attributes of parent classes, not the other way around. Although you can generalize an instance of Daily to an Appointment, you lose the ability to call Daily-specific methods on the instance without a cast.

If you want to access occursOn() in both Daily and Appointment, you need to declare the method in the Appointment class so that it is inherited by its subclasses.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Appointment doesn't have an `occursOn()`.

If you have `maleDuck extends duck` and you give me either one, but only tell me it's a duck, I can make it `quack()`, but i don't know if it `layseggs()`.

```
Duck ladyDuck = new FemaleDuck();
ladyDuck.layseggs();  //WRONG, not a ducks lay eggs

FemaleDuck ladyDuck = new FemaleDuck();
ladyDuck.layseggs();  //CORRECT, it's clear we're dealing with female ducks
```

What's interesting about polymorphism is when we `overload` the `quack()` (pseudo-code:)...

```
Duck[] ducks = { new MaleDuck(), new FemaleDuck() };
foreach (duck in ducks) { duck.quack() };
Assert("1 manish quack and 1 ladyish quack just happened");
```

...we can treat them identically and access their unique behavior. But we can't just go calling `layegg()` on the members of that array, because the `MaleDucks` would struggle.

Check out some [tutorials](http://www.java-made-easy.com/polymorphism-in-java.html) on Polymorphism.

I don't know why I didn't put this in terms of appointments. But I feel it's just unwritten law that all polymorphism examples must be explained in terms of either cars or animals. :D

Comment: Thank you so much. It too a little bit of tinkering with and I had to refresh my memory about inheritance but I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your Appointment class needs a method occursOn, it doesn't need to be filled.
then you can override it in classes that override appointment.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a `Daily` as an `Appointment`, you must downcast the variable to its proper type in order to access `Daily`'s `occursOn` method:

```
 Appointment appt1;
 appt1 = new Daily("See Doctor", "01/01/2015");
 ((Daily) appt).occursOn();
```

If a type is declared as an `Appointment`, then the compiler is only aware of `Appointment` methods, even if the underlying type is `Daily`. 'Downcasting' is the process by which you refine a reference's type to one of it's derived classes. Note that you can only downcast to a derived type when the underlying class is actually of the derived type, for instance, if you try this:

```
 Appointment appt1;
 appt1 = new Appointment("See Doctor");
 ((Daily) appt).occursOn(); //Compiler throws an error!!
```

You will end up in a world of hurt.

Comment: While this is true. I wouldn't recommend down-casting. If you want a `Daily` and are going to do `Daily` things to it, just ask for a  `Daily`

Comment: Definitely true, though it serves as a good example for what is actually going on when you pass a `Daily` object into a function that takes an `Appointment` object. It's polymorphism at work. The object retains its underlying identity while passing for a parent type.